# Erro Object of class daoMaterias could not be converted to string in daoMaterias.php on line 33

Tags: php, pdo

Na hora de chamar a função de cadastrar matérias eu encontro esse erro : Object of class daoMaterias could not be converted to string, Alguém sabe como resolver ?

```
class daoMaterias
    {

        private $pdo;


            /* Função para cadastrar materias */


            public function cadastrarMaterias($nome, $mediaMinima){


                $this->pdo = new conexao();

                $cadastrarMaterias = $this->pdo->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO  materias (id, nome, mediaMinima) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)");

                $cadastrarMaterias->bindValue(1, $nome);

                $cadastrarMaterias->bindValue(2, $mediaMinima);

                $cadastrarMaterias->execute();

                session_start();

                if($cadastrarMaterias->rowCount() > 0 )
                {
                    $_SESSION["cadastrarMaterias"] = "Matéria cadastrada com sucesso ! " ;
                }else{
                    $_SESSION["cadastrarMaterias"] = "Erro ao cadastrar matéria";
                }
            }
```

Essa seria a linha 33 : `$cadastrarMaterias->bindValue(1, $nome);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro indica que está a atribuir um objeto como string.

Exemplo que simula o erro:

```
<?php

$x = (object)array(); // objeto para teste

//echo $x; //provoca o erro

$y = 'foo'.$x; // também provoca o erro
```

Vá na linha 33, uma linha antes e adicione um breakpoint para testes

```
var_dump($nome); exit;
$cadastrarMaterias->bindValue(1, $nome);
```

Com isso poderá enxergar o que está carregado na variável `$nome`.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado